# Can someone tell me where did that come form

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

[image: form where]

Can someone tell me where did that come from, I do all the steps correctly but I don't know where did that$fv*(1)$ come from, thanks!

Comment: What is the $x$-derivative of $f_v\cdot x$ ? It should give you two terms.

Comment: I know it's the Partial of that but why take it and add it?

Comment: You want $w_{xy}$ and you know $w_y$ and $w_{xy} = \frac{\partial w_y}{\partial x}$ so taking the partial derivative of the first line gives you the second. The term I mentioned is in $w_y$ and it's a product of two terms so you use the product rule to find the $x$-derivative of this term which gives you two terms, one of them will be the one in red. Do you manage to get this? The final term ($\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f_{u}$) comes from the $f_u$ term in $w_y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the product rule. The derivative we're calculating is
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial (x f_v)}{ \partial x} &=  \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} \right) f_v + x \left( \frac{\partial f_v}{\partial x} \right) \\
&=  1\times f_v + x \left( \frac{\partial f_v}{\partial x} \right) \\
\end{split}
$$